# gtk.css in user .config directory: documentation on use?

Tags: libreoffice, gtk

For example, to change the cursor size in gtk apps (such as libreoffice) we can put an entry to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

```
* { -GtkWidget-cursor-aspect-ratio: 0.2; }
```

This was suggested by Mark in another question on this site. [Libreoffice writer: typing cursor appearance (not mouse pointer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027877/libreoffice-writer-typing-cursor-appearance-not-mouse-pointer).

I want now to change the color of the cursor (aka caret), but

```
* { -GtkWidget-cursor-color: #00FF00; }
```

has no effect.

In looking into this, I find that all the documentation on gtk.css and GDKWidget refers to its use in a C program. That is a bigger project than I'm eager for right now so I'm hoping for a pointer to some documentation on this gtk.css file as it is used in the ~/.config directory.

Comment: `* { caret-color: #00FF00; }` works in some applications, but not in LibreOffice.

Comment: @DK Bose Hm. Wonder if it's worth a bug report. I'll give that a try.